# How to parse response table with PHPExcel import Excel file to input tag (example : autofill input id="fname" to Hello and input id="lname" to World)?

Tags: php, html, excel, phpexcel, html-input

How to parse this response table with PHPExcel import Excel file into desired input fields (example : autofill `input id="fname"` to Hello and autofill `input id="lname"` to World)?

I can to

**1.** send file to PHP.

**2.** parse EXCEL file with third-party library (use PHPExcel library).

**3.** create response for AJAX/POST into HTML page.

but I can't parse this response table with PHPExcel import Excel file into desired input fields (example : autofill `input id="fname"` to Hello and autofill `input id="lname"` to World).

Sample code and file at the bottom.

1. `excelimport.xlsx` (Excel file)

[Download Link](http://doanga2007.github.io/excelimport.xlsx)

2. `excelimport.php` (PHP Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2 {display: inline;}
</style>
<script>
var _validFileExtensions = [".xls", ".xlsx", ".csv"];    
function ValidateSingleInput(oInput) {
    if (oInput.type == "file") {
        var sFileName = oInput.value;
         if (sFileName.length > 0) {
            var blnValid = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, 

sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                    blnValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!blnValid) {
                alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", 

"));
                oInput.value = "";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES['excel']) && $_FILES['excel']['error']==0) {
        require_once "PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";
        $tmpfname = $_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'];
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        echo "<table class=\"table table-sm\">";
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
             echo "<tr><td scope=\"row\">";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";    
}
?>

<form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <h2 for="myfile1">Select files : </h2>
         <input type = "file" name = "excel" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this)" />
         <input type = "submit"/><br><br>
</form>

    <h2 for="fname">First name : </h2><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" 

value=""><br><br>
    <h2 for="lname">Last name : </h2><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" 

value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2">

</body>
</html>
```

I use PHPExcel library to download with [link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news** : I have answer to parse response table with PHPExcel import Excel file to input tag (example : autofill input id=“fname” to Hello and input id=“lname” to World) with my full source code.

I have answer credit with [link.](http://niik.in/que_3010_6713)

1. `excelimport.xlsx` (Excel file)

[Download Link](http://doanga2007.github.io/excelimport.xlsx)

2. `excelimport.php` (PHP Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    h2 {display: inline;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform1" id="myform1">
    <h2 for="myfile1">Select files : </h2><input type="file" name="excelFile" id="excelFile" /><br><br>
    <h2 for="fname">First name : </h2><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <h2 for="lname">Last name : </h2><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){


    // เมื่อฟอร์มการเรียกใช้ evnet submit ข้อมูล        
    $("#excelFile").on("change",function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // ปิดการใช้งาน submit ปกติ เพื่อใช้งานผ่าน ajax

        // เตรียมข้อมูล form สำหรับส่งด้วย  FormData Object
       var formData = new FormData($("#myform1")[0]);

        // ส่งค่าแบบ POST ไปยังไฟล์ read_excel.php รูปแบบ ajax แบบเต็ม
        $.ajax({
            url: 'read_excel.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            /*async: false,*/
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);  // ทดสอบแสดงค่า  ดูผ่านหน้า console
/*              การใช้งาน console log เพื่อ debug javascript ใน chrome firefox และ ie 
                http://www.ninenik.com/content.php?arti_id=692 via @ninenik         */
                $("#fname").val(data.A2);
                $("#lname").val(data.B2);
        });     

    });


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. `read_excel.php` (PHP Code)

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");    
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");         
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');
// http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['excelFile']['name']) && $_FILES['excelFile']['name']!=""){
    $tmpFile = $_FILES['excelFile']['tmp_name'];  
    $fileName = $_FILES['excelFile']['name'];  // เก็บชื่อไฟล์
    $_fileup = $_FILES['excelFile'];
    $info = pathinfo($fileName);
    $allow_file = array("csv","xls","xlsx");
/*  print_r($info);         // ข้อมูลไฟล์   
    print_r($_fileup);*/
    if($fileName!="" && in_array($info['extension'],$allow_file)){
        // อ่านไฟล์จาก path temp ชั่วคราวที่เราอัพโหลด
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmpFile);      


        // ดึงข้อมูลของแต่ละเซลในตารางมาไว้ใช้งานในรูปแบบตัวแปร array
        $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();

        // วนลูปแสดงข้อมูล
        $v=1;
        $json_data = array();
        foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
            // ค่าสำหรับดูว่าเป็นคอลัมน์ไหน เช่น A B C ....
            $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
            // คำสำหรับดูว่าเป็นแถวที่เท่าไหร่ เช่น 1 2 3 .....
            $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
            // ค่าของข้อมูลในเซลล์นั้นๆ เช่น A1 B1 C1 ....
            $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();          

            // เท่านี้เราก็สามารถแสดงข้อมูลจากการอ่านไฟล์ได้แล้ว และสามารถนำข้อมูลเหล่านี้
            // ทำการบันทักลงฐานข้อมูล หรือแสดงได้เลย
            $json_data["$column$row"] = $data_value;
//            echo $v." ----  ".$data_value."<br>";
             $v++;
        }       
         // แปลง array เป็นรูปแบบ json string  
        if(isset($json_data)){  
            $json= json_encode($json_data);    
            if(isset($_GET['callback']) && $_GET['callback']!=""){    
            echo $_GET['callback']."(".$json.");";        
            }else{    
            echo $json;    
            }    
        }        
    }
} 
?>
```

I use PHPExcel library to download with [link.](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/)